# Microsoft Identity returnURL not working on direct links

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to use the .NET 5 hosted Blazor template to setup Authentication via Microsoft.Identity.Web and Azure AD (single tenant). The template appears to be working, I am able to authenticate to my tenant and access restricted pages.

However the returnURL doesn't appear to work if I use a direct link to a page needing Authorization.

Example from the template

I go to https://localhost:5001/ which is the unrestricted main page. I press on the Fetch data link on the page https://localhost:5001/fetchdata . The Microsoft login screens appear in a popup, I login and automatically return to https://localhost:5001/fetchdata

If instead I directly open a browser and go to https://localhost:5001/fetchdata. I get the Microsoft login screens directly in the page not a popup and when I have authenticated I am sent to the home page https://localhost:5001/.

Is this expected behaviour? It would seem to mean I can't provide direct links to restricted pages.

Comment: This is not the behaviour I am seeing. What is the redirect in `RedirectToLogin.razor.cs`?

Comment: @BrianParker In the OnInitialized it has the line Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}"); I believe it is submitting correctly with returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Ffetchdata . The main difference I am spotting in the two different routes is I get the popup login version when going to the homepage first and the in window one when I do the direct link.

Comment: @BrianParker in fact I have just added options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect"; to the Program.cs to force that mode of authentication rather than the popup and now always get redirected to home so it appears to be an issue with that login method.

Comment: mine just reads `builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);`